# Module name conflict in Python, how to resolve?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I came across a file in our project, called - wait for it - celery.py. Yes, and celery.py imports from the installed celery module (see http://www.celeryproject.org/) which is not an issue because the project's celery.py uses

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

before importing from the installed celery module. Now, the problem comes from djcelery (django-celery) which also would like to import from celery (the installed one, not the project celery.py). This is where the clash comes because  djcelery encounters the project's celery.py before it encounters the installed celery.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and most sane way to do it is to refactor you project and change the name of the file.

There are probably some way strange way around this, but I would hardly consider that worth it, as it would most likely complicate your code, and make it prone to errors.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Chirila Alexandru said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20937233/4279), just rename the module.

You could also:

- add `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of the file that imports [`celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org/) (to import your `celery.py` instead, you could use `from project.your_app import celery`)
- use explicit relative import, to import your `celery.py`: `from . import celery`